# Why does my computer not display a log in box?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, login, windows-update, safe-mode

I started up my computer as normal, and clicked on my username, I expected the log-in box to appear, but after 10 minutes nothing happens.

So I got my other spare computer and searched up the problem, I found out that I had to boot into safe mode and use system restore to restore the problem. It worked, a week later the same thing happened, I fixed it the same way. This time it happened again, I tried to fix it the same way but nothing changed, I tried the same thing again, nothing happened.

So now I don't know what to do. I was thinking of re-installing windows 7 pro, but I thought that there must be another way to solve the problem. By the way, every time it happened, it occurred just after my PC installed and optimized windows updates. So it probably has something to do with this or the registry.

Notes:

HP 6730b

Answer (score 0):

If System Restore resolved the issue, but then it appeared a week later, you need to think about possible changes you may have done to your system in that time frame:

- Have you installed any software?
- Have you attached any new devices on your PC that may have downloaded or required software to be installed?
- Have you installed any plugins or such required by websites?  Accidentally installed any browser toolbars?

From there you can deduce what programs might be giving you a problem and see about modifying their configuration or uninstalling them.

It is also possible that Windows Update has updated a driver to a version your system doesn't like.  Go into the Windows Updates control panel and uncheck any driver or device updates, before allowing them to install.

You also might try checking your systems Event Viewer (under Administrative Tools) for any clues.  Some of this stuff can be cryptic and technical in nature but it may help you find out the name of a program or Windows component that you can further look at.

Last, try letting it run for up to 30 minutes.  A pop up or message might be visible after it finally does log in that can give you more clues.

Comment: He can't check Event Viewer if he can't log in.

Comment: Sorry to be unclear - might be worth checking Event Viewer after the system restore, around the time of the failed login.  Or check if it the login is eventually successful after waiting more than 10 minutes.

Comment: turned my computer off, after 6 hours I turned it on, and no problems.

Comment: I am getting a lot of "The winlogon notification subscriber <GPClient> was unavailable to handle a notification event."

Answer (score 0):

I would advise doing a quick reinstall. It's not a big deal and will fix this problem once and for all- you have corrupt Windows files or registry entries that may be very hard to positively identify.

However, if you *really* want to avoid that because you are not used to doing it- then do a repair install (this will keep most of your software).

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html